# Woocommerce checkout not working for guest users

Tags: wordpress

From today woocommerce checkout not working for guest users. guests are not able to add product to cart or remove products from cart. No cache plugin installed in my site.  Enable guest checkout option in the woocommerce settings section is also enabled. There is no new plugin added to get a plugin conflict. Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got fixed. Fast Cgi cache was enabled in our server. We excluded the cart page from the cache.